# Matrix in Chord Diagram

Tags: javascript, chord-diagram

I am new to js and I want to draw a chord diagram for a dataset looks like this:

```
From    To
A          B
A          C
A          C
B          C
B          A
C          A
```

I have used the below coding but it does not work:

```
   d3.csv('data/email1.csv', function (error, data) {
        var mpr = chordMpr(data);
```

`mpr.addValuesToMap('From')
      .addValuesToMap('To')
      .setFilter(function (row, a, b) {
        return (row.From === a.name && row.To === b.name) ||
               (row.From === b.name && row.To === a.name);
      })
      .setAccessor(function (recs, a, b) {
        if (!recs[0]) return 0;
        return recs.length;
      });
     drawChords(mpr.getMatrix(), mpr.getMap());
  });`

Can anyone help? Many thanks!!!